# Apache POI to modify existing excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have been searching for examples on how to copy data from a csv file to an existing excel file.. but there are none. I tried to come up with it on my own but I cant seem to figure out how to copy things into an excel file starting from a specific column and row. I tried it with a csv and this loop works to copy data from a csv to another csv:

```
while ((text) != null){
    //wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.println(text);
text=CSVFile.readLine();
if (text==null)
break;
}
```

But I have no clue how to copy data from a csv to an excel file (and have no clue where to start either)

Answer (score 1):

To read contents from a csv file, you can use a nice utility called supercsv. It can populate java beans with your CSV contents. Then you can use POI to edit the existing excel file. It should be easy to get a cell(using row and column in excel) and update its values. Please check here for example http://thinktibits.blogspot.in/2012/12/Update-Modify-Excel-File-Java-POI-Example.html